# Find out which classes of a given API are used

Tags: java, reflection, import, bytecode

In a Java Project of mine, I would like to find out programmatically which classes from a given API are used. Is there a good way to do that? Through source code parsing or bytecode parsing maybe? Because Reflection won't be of any use, I'm afraid.

To make things simpler: there are no wildcard imports (`import com.mycompany.api.*;`) anywhere in my project, no fully qualified field or variable definitions (`private com.mycompany.api.MyThingy thingy;`) nor any [`Class.forName(...)`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#forName%28java.lang.String%29) constructs. Given these limitations, it boils down to parsing import statements, I guess. Is there a preferred approach to do this?

Comment: Bash script (using for instance egrep) is not an option?

Comment: Not really. a) I need it in java code, b) it needs to run on windows and *x

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can discover the classes using [ASM](http://asm.ow2.org/)'s [`Remapper`](http://asm.ow2.org/asm32/javadoc/user/org/objectweb/asm/commons/Remapper.html) class (believe it or not). This class is actually meant to replace all occurrences of a class name within bytecode. For your purposes, however, it doesn't need to replace anything.

This probably doesn't make a whole lot of sense, so here is an example...

First, you create a subclass of `Remapper` whose only purpose in life is to intercept all calls to the [`mapType(String)`](http://asm.ow2.org/asm32/javadoc/user/org/objectweb/asm/commons/Remapper.html#mapType%28java.lang.String%29) method, recording its argument for later use.

```
public class ClassNameRecordingRemapper extends Remapper {

    private final Set<? super String> classNames;

    public ClassNameRecordingRemapper(Set<? super String> classNames) {
        this.classNames = classNames;
    }

    @Override
    public String mapType(String type) {
        classNames.add(type);
        return type;
    }

}
```

Now you can write a method like this:

```
public Set<String> findClassNames(byte[] bytecode) {
    Set<String> classNames = new HashSet<String>();

    ClassReader classReader = new ClassReader(bytecode);
    ClassWriter classWriter = new ClassWriter(classReader, 0);

    ClassNameRecordingRemapper remapper = new ClassNameRecordingRemapper(classNames);
    classReader.accept(remapper, 0);

    return classNames;
}
```

It's your responsibility to actually obtain all classes' bytecode.

---

### EDIT by seanizer (OP)

I am accepting this answer, but as the above code is not quite correct, I will insert the way I used this:

```
public static class Collector extends Remapper{

    private final Set<Class<?>> classNames;
    private final String prefix;

    public Collector(final Set<Class<?>> classNames, final String prefix){
        this.classNames = classNames;
        this.prefix = prefix;
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritDoc}
     */
    @Override
    public String mapDesc(final String desc){
        if(desc.startsWith("L")){
            this.addType(desc.substring(1, desc.length() - 1));
        }
        return super.mapDesc(desc);
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritDoc}
     */
    @Override
    public String[] mapTypes(final String[] types){
        for(final String type : types){
            this.addType(type);
        }
        return super.mapTypes(types);
    }

    private void addType(final String type){
        final String className = type.replace('/', '.');
        if(className.startsWith(this.prefix)){
            try{
                this.classNames.add(Class.forName(className));
            } catch(final ClassNotFoundException e){
                throw new IllegalStateException(e);
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public String mapType(final String type){
        this.addType(type);
        return type;
    }

}

public static Set<Class<?>> getClassesUsedBy(
    final String name,   // class name
    final String prefix  // common prefix for all classes
                         // that will be retrieved
    ) throws IOException{
    final ClassReader reader = new ClassReader(name);
    final Set<Class<?>> classes =
        new TreeSet<Class<?>>(new Comparator<Class<?>>(){

            @Override
            public int compare(final Class<?> o1, final Class<?> o2){
                return o1.getName().compareTo(o2.getName());
            }
        });
    final Remapper remapper = new Collector(classes, prefix);
    final ClassVisitor inner = new EmptyVisitor();
    final RemappingClassAdapter visitor =
        new RemappingClassAdapter(inner, remapper);
    reader.accept(visitor, 0);
    return classes;
}
```

Here's a main class to test it using:

```
public static void main(final String[] args) throws Exception{
    final Collection<Class<?>> classes =
        getClassesUsedBy(Collections.class.getName(), "java.util");
    System.out.println("Used classes:");
    for(final Class<?> cls : classes){
        System.out.println(" - " + cls.getName());
    }

}
```

And here's the Output:

```
Used classes:
 - java.util.ArrayList
 - java.util.Arrays
 - java.util.Collection
 - java.util.Collections
 - java.util.Collections$1
 - java.util.Collections$AsLIFOQueue
 - java.util.Collections$CheckedCollection
 - java.util.Collections$CheckedList
 - java.util.Collections$CheckedMap
 - java.util.Collections$CheckedRandomAccessList
 - java.util.Collections$CheckedSet
 - java.util.Collections$CheckedSortedMap
 - java.util.Collections$CheckedSortedSet
 - java.util.Collections$CopiesList
 - java.util.Collections$EmptyList
 - java.util.Collections$EmptyMap
 - java.util.Collections$EmptySet
 - java.util.Collections$ReverseComparator
 - java.util.Collections$ReverseComparator2
 - java.util.Collections$SelfComparable
 - java.util.Collections$SetFromMap
 - java.util.Collections$SingletonList
 - java.util.Collections$SingletonMap
 - java.util.Collections$SingletonSet
 - java.util.Collections$SynchronizedCollection
 - java.util.Collections$SynchronizedList
 - java.util.Collections$SynchronizedMap
 - java.util.Collections$SynchronizedRandomAccessList
 - java.util.Collections$SynchronizedSet
 - java.util.Collections$SynchronizedSortedMap
 - java.util.Collections$SynchronizedSortedSet
 - java.util.Collections$UnmodifiableCollection
 - java.util.Collections$UnmodifiableList
 - java.util.Collections$UnmodifiableMap
 - java.util.Collections$UnmodifiableRandomAccessList
 - java.util.Collections$UnmodifiableSet
 - java.util.Collections$UnmodifiableSortedMap
 - java.util.Collections$UnmodifiableSortedSet
 - java.util.Comparator
 - java.util.Deque
 - java.util.Enumeration
 - java.util.Iterator
 - java.util.List
 - java.util.ListIterator
 - java.util.Map
 - java.util.Queue
 - java.util.Random
 - java.util.RandomAccess
 - java.util.Set
 - java.util.SortedMap
 - java.util.SortedSet
```

Comment: sounds like exactly what I'm looking for, I'll have a look at it, thanks (+1)

Comment: That looks groovy! I especially like the output. I just realized that the "class names" you are receiving appear to be the *internal* class names. ASM supplies the [`Type`](http://asm.ow2.org/asm33/javadoc/user/org/objectweb/asm/Type.html) class to help you with this. For example, you can use `Type type = Type.getType(internalClassName)`. From here, you can then call `type.getClassName()`, which is the class name you're used to.

Comment: @Bohzo: This is a hilarious work-around to Stack Overflow's lack of a messaging system! :) I want you to have that answer.

Comment: I like this, but it misses classes used inside methods; is there any way to pick up those references as well?

Comment: Very cool. Looks like EmptyVisitor has been removed. What to use instead  https://github.com/bmc/javautil/pull/15/files?diff=split ?

Answer (score 4):

I think the following might help you out:

1. [Class Dependency Analyzer](http://www.dependency-analyzer.org/)
2. [Dependency Finder](http://depfind.sourceforge.net/Resources.html)

Comment: a) Thanks for answering b) I don't think either of these will help, as I want to run some java code based on the results automatically.

Comment: Dependency Finder is open source. You can check out and integrate the the code in your project or you can do textual analysis on the report generated.

Comment: Thanks for the answer (+1), but there are several technologies listed here that do exactly what I'm looking for so I won't inspect the close calls.

Answer (score 2):

1. [Compiler Tree API](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/jdk/api/javac/tree/com/sun/source/util/Trees.html)
2. byte code analysis - the fully qualified names should be in the constant pool

Comment: I'm currently playing with byte code analysis using bcel, but it's a pain. I'd prefer the Compiler Tree API, but what's the starting point? (I have no Compilation Task and no ProcessingEnvironment)

Comment: You can run an annotation processor - http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/annotation/processing/AbstractProcessor.html on ur source code to get a ProcessingEnvironment

Comment: I know how to start an annotation processor, but I don't want to do this from within the compile process, nor start a second compile process.

Comment: I don't know how to use the Compiler Tree API without using a compile process.  This is probably not suitable for you.

Answer (score 1):

Something like this perhaps:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

public class FileTraverser {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        visitAllDirsAndFiles(new File("source_directory"));
    }

    public static void visitAllDirsAndFiles(File root) {
        if (root.isDirectory())
            for (String child : root.list())
                visitAllDirsAndFiles(new File(root, child));
        process(root);
    }

    private static void process(File f) {

        Pattern p = Pattern.compile("(?=\\p{javaWhitespace}*)import (.*);");
        if (f.isFile() && f.getName().endsWith(".java")) {
            try {
                Scanner s = new Scanner(f);
                String cls = "";
                while (null != (cls = s.findWithinHorizon(p, 0)))
                    System.out.println(cls);
            } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

You may want to take comments into account, but it shouldn't be too hard. You could also make sure you only look for imports before the class declaration.

Comment: This is exactly the way I would hack up a solution myself (+1 for that :-) ), but I am looking for a solution that actually understands either source or byte code.

Answer (score 1):

I use [DependencyFinder](http://depfind.sourceforge.net/) exactly for that purpose. It can analyse bytecode and extract all dependencies, then dump a report in txt or xml format (see the DependencyExtractor tool). You should be able to programatically analyse the report from your application's code.

I have integrated this in my build process in order to check that certain APIs are NOT used by an application.

Comment: I'll upvote this because it's a good answer, but I don't think DependencyFinder and I can ever be friends :-)

Answer (score 0):

You may want to use [STAN](http://stan4j.com/) for that.

The "Couplings View" visualizes the dependencies to your API in a nice graph.

Comment: Nice, but not an answer to my question, I need a programmatic way to get at the used classes, not a pretty report.

Answer (score 0):

If you use Eclipse. Try using the profiling tools. It doesn't only tells which classes are being used, but tells much more about it. The results will be something like:

[image]

There is a very good quickstart at:

http://www.eclipse.org/tptp/home/documents/tutorials/profilingtool/profilingexample_32.html

Comment: Try reading the question and the other answers carefully next time. I was looking for something I could use programmatically. What you are suggesting is a nice tool, but not the answer to my question.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Adam Paynter, It helped me. But what I was looking for is to fetch the dependent classes (recursively)- which means take a feature from a projects. So, need to get all the classes associated with a particular classes and again the used classes of those classes and so on. and also get the jars. So, I Created my own [Java Dependency Resolver project](http://code.google.com/p/java-dependency-resolver/) Which will find the dependent Classes/jars for a particular class in a Project. I am sharing it here that may come to any use of some body.