# static analysis to find out all the referenced class from a root in java

Tags: java, static-analysis, object-graph

In Java language. Given a root class, I want to find out all the classes referenced by the root(the whole object graph). Java Reflect is not sufficient. Because :

```
Class A{
   List list = new ArrayList();

   public void add(Object obj){
      list.add(obj);
   }

   public void add2(){
      Ent ent = new Ent();
      add(ent);
   }
}
```

Using Reflect, I can easily get **"Class A contains (Object)"**. 
But actually what I want is **“Class A contains (Ent)”**.

I want to analyze the java src code or .class file to find out the whole object graph statically, instead of runtime.

Is there anyone can help me ? Thanks!

Comment: looks like http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3734825/find-out-which-classes-of-a-given-api-are-used

Answer (score 1):

depfind tools help to track dependencies and take some actions. It can find outbound dependencies.

> Showing Only Outbound Dependencies
>
> Outbound dependencies show you who a given programming element depends
>   upon. They are very useful when partitioning programming elements and
>   figuring out what other classes a given class needs in order to run.
>   Dependency Finder uses a textual notation to display them:
>
> ```
> programming element
>     --> dependable 1
>     --> dependable 2
>         ...
> ```
>
> When there are a lot of dependencies, either because the graph is very
>   big or an element is highly connected, it is useful to filter out the
>   other dependencies so that outbound ones stand out and are easier to
>   read.

http://depfind.sourceforge.net/Manual.html#ShowingOnlyOutboundDependencies

Comment: @ DON1101 : Good to know it is useful.   Please check the question mentioned by nullix. It has more options listed