# List projects Module dependency without maven programatically

Tags: weblogic, jmx, dependency-management, wlst

We are using Weblogic Server.We need to determine all projects dependencies programatically.None of projects uses Maven.For example A project need B and C project we want to list these relations. 
Previusly I had exprienced listing projects and set datasource programatically using wlst and JMX.But I couldn't find any information about my need.Is it possible to find an application's dependencies deployed in a weblogic server ? Any help will appreciated .

Comment: Suggestions and alternative ways would be helpfull

Comment: You're looking for run time dependencies? That may be extremely difficult. A different option if you don't want to use Maven is something like JBoss tattletale http://www.jboss.org/tattletale but that's still not programmatic... There are other options like: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3734825/find-out-which-classes-of-a-given-api-are-used