# Java collect all used classes from bytecode

Tags: java, class, bytecode, collect

I trying to implement a RemoteClassLoader which copy and load all classes which will be used in runtime. First I need to collect the used Classes, I found a solution:

[Find out which classes of a given API are used](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3734825/find-out-which-classes-of-a-given-api-are-used)

but this is not exactly what a need, it collect only the "visible" class usages, just like loading the class and iterating all of declared field and methods, and collecting all types.
I have a class which contains only static methods, instance of this method is not used, so it will be never given to a function or will be a filed, and so I can't see that class.

Naturally the bytecode file contains the name of this class:

```
strings TestClass.class | grep -i "json"

gives: org/json/JSONObject
```

And yes that class I search and not fond.
How can I find it? And the others which I use only in functions.

Comment: I know classes which used via reflect will be not shown.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest, albeit conservative method is to simply take all of the `Class_info` entries from the constant pool. In order to call a method or access a field of a class, there must be a constant pool entry for that class (not counting reflection and not counting overriding methods in subclasses).

There are a number of tools out there that will parse a classfile and give you access to this. Reflection of course is much harder, and in general undecideable.

Edit: This won't include type descriptors, which are just `Utf8_info`s. If you want to find classes used as types as well, there are two approaches. Either you can go through all the Utf8s and include everything that looks like a descriptor (which may have false positives in rare cases), or you can go through the classfile and find all the type descriptor references.